# Generate a matrix where the maximum of each column is maintained with the other entries zeroed

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 10 by 1000 matrix and would like to generate another matrix such that I keep the largest element in each column and null or "zero" the remaining 9 entries.

Is it possible to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Got any code for us to look at?

Answer (score 2):

I usually don't answer questions of this type (i.e. *give me teh coodz*), but I'm answering primarily for longevity.  It's an interesting problem to solve.

In any case, what you're asking for is pretty easy.  Use [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and operate amongst the columns individually for your matrix and use the second output of `max`.  These give you the row locations for each column that gives you the max.  The first output of `max` gives you the corresponding maximum values at each column.

Simply create a zero matrix and use the second output of `max` to index into this blank matrix and place the corresponding maximum values retrieved from the first output into this matrix.  What you are only given are the **row** locations for each column.  Therefore, you need an additional call to [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to complete the assignment where we need to find the linear indices that correspond to the location of each maximum value per column, and we assign the maximum of each column to each corresponding location per column.

Therefore, given that your matrix is `X`, just do this:

```
[Y,ind] = max(X, [], 1);
out = zeros(size(X));
vals = sub2ind(size(X), ind, 1:size(X,2));
out(vals) = Y;
```

## Sample run

```
>> rng(123123);
>> X = randi(10,5,5)

X =

     4     5     4     8     7
    10     2     8     7     2
     3     1     9     1    10
     9     6     6     4     4
     8     3     5     2     4
```

After running the code at the beginning, we get:

```
out =

     0     0     0     8     0
    10     0     0     0     0
     0     0     9     0    10
     0     6     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

## Caveat

The above method assumes **unique** entries per column.  Should you have a column that has multiple instances of the same maximum value, only **one** of those values get saved and the rest of the column - including the other shared maximum values - get nulled to zero.  Specifically, the first instance of the maximum value that gets encountered gets saved, and the other values disappear.

Comment: @mohamed - I made a slight error.  Please refresh the post.  Also, if this does work for you, consider accepting my answer.  That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left just below the up and down voting buttons.  Whenever you're able to.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way. This keeps all column entries that are equal to the column maximum, even if there are several such entries.

Let `X` denote the matrix and `Y` the result. Then:

```
Y = X.*bsxfun(@eq, X, max(X));
```

Comment: Oh that's certainly clever. +1.  This also allows for multiple maximum values per column.